# JWK management in openID Connect provider server

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid-connect, openid, jwk

I want to implement an OpenID Connect server, I don't know how should I manage JWK for clients? just a single JWK to sing all JWT tokens or generate JWK per client?
I appreciate any tutorial link to help me.

Answer (score 1):

Each client should have their own JWK. [OpenID Connect Dynamic Client Registration 1.0](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-registration-1_0.html) defines `jwks` and `jwks_ur` as client metadata.

Comment: But I see [Auth0 private keys are unique per tenant](https://auth0.com/docs/tokens/manage-signing-keys), I think if our app is multi-tenant, we should create a public/private key per tenant, otherwise, just a single public/private key pair is enough.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I researched about it and what I got is this:

- Google uses a single endpoint to get its JWK and verify signatures. no matter for what clients.
- Auth0 uses a single private key per tenant, so it uses a single public/private key for all clients in that tenant.
- Keycloak uses a single key per realm. so all clients in that realm use that single public key.

**My Conclusion**
If our OP is multi-tenant, public/private keys can be unique per tenant, otherwise uses a single public/private key pair for all clients. Please note we should have key rotation also.